# Insert audit.net data into database

Tags: audit.net

I have created the following code which generates a JSON of the changes that have been made using Audit.net and Audit.EntityFramework.Core;

```
                AuditNet.Configuration.Setup()
               .UseEntityFramework(_ => _
                   .AuditTypeMapper(t => typeof(AuditLog))
                   .AuditEntityAction<AuditLog>((ev, entry, entity) =>
                   {
                       entity.AuditData = entry.ToJson();
                       entity.EntityType = entry.EntityType.Name;
                       entity.AuditAction = entry.Action;
                       entity.AuditDate = DateTime.Now;
                       entity.AuditUser = Environment.UserName;
                       entity.TablePk = entry.PrimaryKey.First().Value.ToString();
                   })
                   .IgnoreMatchedProperties(true));
       


        AuditNet.Configuration.Setup()
            .UseFileLogProvider(config => config
                .FilenamePrefix("Event_")
                .Directory(@"C:\Users\Cristian Reche\source\repos\people-back"))
            .WithCreationPolicy(EventCreationPolicy.InsertOnStartReplaceOnEnd)
            .WithAction(x => x.OnScopeCreated(scope => scope.SetCustomField("ApplicationId", "Pepople-Back Auditoria")));
```

But I need to insert that data into my database. It's possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should call `Audit.Core.Configuration.Setup()` only once. Otherwise the second call will override the configuration.